# Seasoning carbon steel wok

Tags: equipment

Can a new unseasoned carbon steel wok be seasoned after one use (used it for steaming)?
It now has some rust on it. Can it be salvaged?

Comment: Please take the time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) ref: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=season+wok

Comment: Hi Maureen, answers which work for a very rusted wok also work for a slightly rusted wok, you just have less work ahead of you :) So I'm marking it as a duplicate of that older question about a very rusted wok.